# How to separate user session from admin session in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

How to separate user session from admin session in Laravel?

Can Laravel's Multi Auth achieve this?

Is there another way to separate sessions without using Multi Auth? I don't want to use Multi Auth because it looks complicated.

But I want to know whether sessions can be separated with Multi Auth?
How about the following code?

```
// in a user page
$request->session()->put('name', 1);

// in an admin page
var_dump($request->session()->get('name'));
```

what will be output?
1 or null?

In general, separating user session from admin session is a common practice in web application?

Or, you should separate user session from admin session by adding prefix to session keys like this?

```
// in php
$_SESSION['user']['name'] = 1;
$_SESSION['admin']['name'] = 2;
unset($_SESSION['admin']);

// in Laravel
$request->session()->put('user.name', 1);
$request->session()->put('admin.name', 2);
$request->session()->forget('admin');
```

In Laravel's config/sessions.php,
I can't find the option to separate user session from admin session.
The session config file seems to provide just a single session configuration.

Comment: Just a note for you, Laravel sessions are not php sessions.

Comment: Thank you for the note. I didn't know that. Do you know Laravel's session is shared between Multi Auth in Laravel?

Comment: No, Multi auth creates new sessions. if you have auth for admin that session will be only for that admin. However I dont see why this would matter. anything meant for admins should not be authenticated by a session, you should have a guard.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Guard looks unnecessarily difficult for me but maybe I should use it. I will read the Laravel's documentation about guard.

Comment: @MichaelMano the documentation for guard is too difficult. it recommends developers to use a starter kit. but i don't want to use something like that. but the explanation of the documentation seems to difficult to understand without using the starter kit. do you know easier tutorial to set up manually multiple guards without a starter kit and to use them to login and protect routes?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? just create admin users who can only view certain routes? will there be lots or can you hard code some manual ids .e.g. users with the IDS of 1,2,3,4 will be admins

Comment: @MichaelMano I already protected admin views with middleware like you suggested in your answer. I implemented a login feature for admins and users with middlewares I made. but sessions between users and admins are not separated, which is not good for security, i think. What I have to try is to separate their sessions. But now I started thinking that I have to obey Laravel's way of implementing login, which means I have to use multi auth. It is very easy for me to implement a login feature without Laravel's way. But it is too complicated to do it with Laravel's way (multi auth).

Comment: @MichaelMano I added some guards to auth.php and logged in to the multiple guards. but sessions are not separated each other. All the guards share a single session. Have you checked if sessions of guards are shared or separated? Probably it is developer's responsibility to avoid session name collision between multiple login user types. Could you check if sessions are really separated? because I might be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are just wanting to protect some views for admins only.

Here is a basic example of how to make an "Admin", Come up with any solution you want. E.g. create an extra column on your user table if you wish.

First create a method on your user model called isAdmin

```
private const ADMIN_IDS = [
    1,2,3,4
];

public function isAdmin()
{
    return in_array($this->id, self::ADMIN_IDS);
}
```

Then create a middleware https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#defining-middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AdminMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if (auth()->user()->isAdmin()) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        abort(401);
    }
}
```

Within App\Http\Kernel class add the 'admin' middleware we just created (see the second line)

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
];
```

```
Route::get('/admin', function () {
    //
})->middleware(['auth', 'admin']);
```

Comment: thank you for advising me. i decided not to use multi auth or multiple guards. like you said, middleware is good and secure enough for a login feature. in my opinion, laravel's multi auth or guard is overcomplicated and does not have enough flexibility. and about session separation, laravel's auth or guard seem to be nothing to do with sessions or session separation between guards.